# Disable type check for node_modules in vue3 vite project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a node module dependency that throws type errors on build. I would like to ignore those:

`node_modules/vue-slider-component/lib/vue-slider.vue:125:17 - error TS1484: 'StateMap' is a type and must be imported using a type-only import when 'verbatimModuleSyntax' is enabled.`

Here are the relevant scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --",
  "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.app.json --composite false",
}
```

What I've tried:

1. "type-check": "vue-tsc **--skipLibCheck** --noEmit -p tsconfig.app.json --composite false"
2. Set `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` in tsconfig.json
3. Setting 1. and 2. in tsconfig.app.json

Am I missing something?

Relevant devDependencies:

```
"@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
"typescript": "~5.2.0",
"vite": "^4.4.9",
"vue-tsc": "^1.8.11"
```